# Use the plugins layout instead of the apps layout if it is available CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

We have developed a CakePHP (1.3) application which works fine. Before usage users have to login. Nothing new there.

We also created a plugin containing a "sales website". It's styling is completely different from the applications design. The sales website works ok, but the loginpage is now based upon the applications layout (path: /users/login). We would like to apply the sales websites layout. But only when the plugin is available.

Is this possible? And if so, is it possible without the need to add a login method and/or users controller to the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use App::objects('plugin') to get a list of available plugins in your app. just do an array_search fro your plugin name and switch the layout accordingly